# explain command usage

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan

i ran the explain command on my main table in mysql.it showed like

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  xyz     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1722    Using where
```

does this affect the performance of the site? like when i so a select clause ? i have a primary key but this command says primary key as no .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Key - The key column indicates the key
>   (index) that MySQL actually decided to
>   use. The key is NULL if no index was
>   chosen. To force MySQL to use or
>   ignore an index listed in the
>   possible_keys  column, use FORCE
>   INDEX, USE INDEX, or IGNORE INDEX  in
>   your query

From your query result we can see that you have no Index defined for your table because possible_keys column is also NULL.

> A database [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29) is a data structure
>   that improves the speed of data
>   retrieval operations on a database
>   table at the cost of slower writes and
>   increased storage space.

Take a look at this page to see the syntax used to create an index in MySQL:

[CREATE INDEX Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

This page details each column of the explain plan:

[Looking at the MySQL Explain Plan](http://www.dbtuna.com/article.asp?&title=The_MySQL_Explain_Plan&id=14)

Comment: @Leniel Macaferi - but i have a primary field in my table . does that not create a index automatically for that field. or do i need to explicitly specify index?

Comment: You need to explicitly specify/create the index. That's true. No matter if you already have a primary key defined. The concepts of primary key and index are different things.

Comment: @Leniel Macaferi -alter table tablename add index (columnname ) will do it rite

Comment: CREATE INDEX indexname ON tablename (columnname)

Comment: @Leniel Macaferi - basically on what column we need to create a index?
so you say that when i create a primary key/foreign key index is not created,bcos i had read that its created.
see i have 2 columns like alias and product .
alias is the name of the products like samsung and all.and product refers to actual product like mobile,camera. i have created a index on alias column now. but i my where clause i use like where product = 'mobile' . is this okie. will the search be faster?

Comment: Generally you'd create and index for a column that will be used most in the where part of your query. In this case you specified that you're going to use the product column in your where clause. So it makes sense to create an index for the product column instead of the alias column. You'll perceive difference on search time only and only if your table has lots of rows. Otherwise you'll not note the difference at all.

Comment: okie i created a index on product column so now explain command says like 
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE  products  ref  product_name_index  product_name_index  902  const  147  Using where
so now its okie rite.number of rows searched to get the result is also less